# How to configure Rendora server side rendering with Angular 8 app and Apache2

Tags: angular, apache, server-side-rendering

I can't understand how should I configure Rendora to use it in my case.

I have some domain e.g. mydomain.com

Currently I have my Angular 8 app running on my VPS server with configured Apache2 and mydomain.com

I need to configure and run Rendora for server side rendering for (mostly) Facebook scraper.

I can change configuration of my Apache and serve app on local address and port. Is target and backend url should be the same in that case?

But how to setup Rendora to listen on my domain address? I can't set value of Listen.Address to domain name because it requires ip address. I can't start Rendora on IP address of VPS and redirect using .htaccess to this IP because it will change address in browser. But it's not a solution.

How should I proceed?

I was able to run it locally on 127.0.0.1:3001 but I don't know what to do if I want to use domain.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Rendora to listen on a domain address is a bad idea, because Rendora can not do SSL offloading.

This is how I solved it:

```
Apache :443 -> Rendora 127.0.0.1:3001 -> Apache 127.0.0.1:81
```

Do a proxy pass from Apache to Rendora and from Rendora to a new Apache virtualhost that serves the static assets of Angular app.

Comment: how to configure Apache properly?

Comment: In a virtualhost that listens to 443 add these lines:
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/